# How to configure TortoiseGit to only show the top of an untracked directory in the Diff and Commit windows?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a Git repo and I use *TortoiseGit* to handle it, as well as command line Git commands. Inside my repo, there is a folder that is not tracked and is not a part if the repo.

```
MyRepo/
  +-- RepoSubDir/
  |     +-- file1
  |     +-- file2
  |
  +-- UnTrackedDir/
        +-- file3
        +-- file4
```

When I enter `git status` on the command line, I see a section of `Untracked files`. This section shows only `UnTrackedDir/`.

However, when opening TortoiseGit's `Git Diff` dialog, I see a section of `Not Versioned Files`, in which I see all the files in the untracked folder, i.e., `UnTrackedDir/file3` and `UnTrackedDir/file4`. Same thing in the `Git Commit` window.

The actual untracked folder is a library containing dozens of files and subfolders, which add a lot of clutter. Is the a way to configure TortoiseGit to only show the top level folder, like it is done in the `git status` command?

*Note: If there is a better site to ask this question, please point this out.*

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseGit always shows all files in unversioned folders (as of 2.14.0). There is currently no way to configure that behavior.

Why not ignore the UntrackedDir? Instead of writing it into a .gitingore file you could ignore it only in your local repository by using .git/info/exclude (cf. https://luisdalmolin.dev/blog/ignoring-files-in-git-without-gitignore)

Comment: Thanks. The answer to (1) is that b/c it is a collaborative project and I don't want to add a file, which is possibly irrelevant for other developers in the team, to the archive. As of (2), I don't see how it matters here. If you show the whole project, you'll see that directory with all its content.

Comment: Wait... I re-read (1) and got into that link. Looks like this may work *if* I don't have to exclude each and every file in that subfolder.

Comment: With (1) you can exclude the whole subfolder at once or all files, the same .gitignore rules apply

Comment: OK, using the `exclude` file method is a huge improvement, removing dozens of files from the diff window. Unfortunately, it also removes the root of that untracked tree, from both the diff window and from the `git status` command. If possible, I'd like to preserve the directory name itself in the list, the same way it was done with the `git status` command. Is there a way to achieve that?